# How do I stop Java 6.29 trying to reinstall itself?

Tags: windows-7, java

About once I week I get a notice about a new version of Java.  When I let it try to install the update, it always turns out to be version 6.29, which is always determines is already on my machine.  How do I get it to stop and not bother me again?

Comment: [Java RE 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-se-jre-7-download-432155.html) is out.

Comment: How do I get Java RE 7?

Comment: I linked it in my comment. Follow that link and download the appropriate version for your operating system. Uninstall Java 6, and install Java 7.

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed that.  Thank you, Ampersand.

Comment: No worries. Very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Control Panel** > *Java**

Java Control Panel > Update tab

Select from the drop list: **Notify Me: Before downloading**

**Deselect** (uncheck): *Check for Updates Automatically*

Click **Never Check** on the pop up

Click **Apply**

Click **OK**

Alternatively you could just stop the updater from starting with your computer.